# How working position label longtable?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, align, longtable

2 problem:

1. How align "continued table" and \caption text in left?  \raggedright not working
   in this situation.
2. How delete empty line before enumerator?

Source code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}

\title{A longtable example}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{| >{\raggedright}p{0.20\linewidth} 
                  | >{\raggedright}p{0.28\linewidth} 
                  | >{\raggedright}p{0.28\linewidth} 
                  | >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.12\linewidth}|}
   \caption{A sample long table.} \label{tab:long} \\


   First column & First column & First column & First column \\
   \endfirsthead

\multicolumn{3}{c}%
{{ \raggedleft \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page}} \\
\hline \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{{First column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{{Second column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{{Third column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{{Third column}} \\ \hline 
\endhead
   \hline
   Login-1 & \begin{enumerate}
                \item[1)] step1;
                \item[2)] step2;
            \end{enumerate}
             & Doing something & yes \\

   \hline
   Login-1 & \begin{enumerate}
                \item[1)] step1;
                \item[2)] step2;
            \end{enumerate}
             & Doing something & yes \\

   \hline
   Login-1 & \begin{enumerate}
                \item[1)] step1;
                \item[2)] step2;
            \end{enumerate}
             & Doing something & yes \\

   \hline
   Login-1 & \begin{enumerate}
                \item[1)] step1;
                \item[2)] step2;
            \end{enumerate}
             & Doing something & yes \\

   \hline
   Login-1 & \begin{enumerate}
                \item[1)] step1;
                \item[2)] step2;
            \end{enumerate}
             & Doing something & yes \\

   \hline
    Login-1 & \begin{enumerate}
                \item[1)] step1;
                \item[2)] step2;
            \end{enumerate}
             & Doing something & yes \\

   \hline
   Login-1 & \begin{enumerate}
                \item[1)] step1;
                \item[2)] step2;
            \end{enumerate}
             & Doing something & yes \\

   \hline
   Login-1 & \begin{enumerate}
                \item[1)] step1;
                \item[2)] step2;
            \end{enumerate}
             & Doing something & yes \\

   \hline
   Login-1 & \begin{enumerate}
                \item[1)] step1;
                \item[2)] step2;
            \end{enumerate}
             & Doing something & yes \\

   \hline
  \end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\multicolumn{3}{c}%
{{ \raggedleft \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page}} \\
```

a `c` column is a horizontal box like `\mbox` so paragraph settings like `\raggedleft` have no effect, you presumably want

```
\multicolumn{3}{r}%
{\tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page} \\
```

to get a flush right entry.

Comment: Thanks, but how resolve problem with line empty before enumeratot?

Comment: look at the compact list options in the enumitem package @ximet

Comment: How corrected only for this situation?